# Check if an array of posts has posts from a specific category

Tags: terms, count

I have an `$array` that prints out to be as follows.

`Array ( [post-12] => 12 [post-160] => 160 )`

What WordPress function could I use to check how many of the post ID's in the array belong to a specific category, say category with ID 45.

I tried doing the following.

```
$post_id_array = $array;
$category = '45';
$count = count(in_category( $category, $post_id_array ));
echo $count;
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: OK, can some mod transfer this question there?

Comment: You can try to flag it for moderator attention with the explicit reason, but I'm not 100% sure they can do that. Or you can copy/paste and delete this one ;-)

Answer (score 2):

A much faster solution would be to query the database once instead of over and over for each post ex:

```
function count_posts_in_term($posts = array(),$term_taxonomy_id = 0){
    global $wpdb;
    $count = 0 ;
    $count = $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare("SELECT count(object_id) 
            FROM $wpdb->term_relationships 
            WHERE term_taxonomy_id = %s 
            AND object_id IN(".implode(',',$posts).")",
            $term_taxonomy_id
        )
    );
    return $count;
}
```

usage:

```
echo count_posts_in_term($array_of_posts,$cat_term_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully returned the counts using the following code. Just in case someone may later view this question.

```
$count = 0;
$category = '45';
foreach ( $array as $post_id ) {
    if (in_category( $category, $post_id )) {
        $count++;
    }
}
echo $count;
```